# Can I make my data extraction program(oracle database to excel) more effiicient?

Tags: java, excel, oracle, jsp, servlets

I am currently extracting data from a database to an excel using apache.poi. I just wanted to see if it was possible to speed up the extraction process. I have a selection value in my JSP that calls for 3500 rows of data to be extracted and this is the only case that extremely slows up execution. I am creating two separate excel files from the extraction.

The first class is the simple data extraction:

```
    private void createSiteFieldExcel(String workSheetName, List<String> columnHeader, List<MasterDataDto> masterDatatDtoList) {
    XSSFSheet sheet = masterDataWorkbook.createSheet(workSheetName);
    int cellNumber = 0;
    int rowNumber = 0;
    Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(rowNumber++);
    sheet.createFreezePane(0, 1);
    List<MasterDataDto> dataConsistencyList = new ArrayList<MasterDataDto>();
    for (Iterator<String> iterator = columnHeader.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(cellNumber++);
        cell.setCellValue(iterator.next());
        // sets the header to be bold
        cell.setCellStyle(masterDataBoldStyle);
    }
    for (MasterDataDto masterDatatDto : masterDatatDtoList) {
        Row dataRow = sheet.createRow(rowNumber++);
        cellNumber = 0;

        Cell cell = dataRow.createCell(cellNumber++);
        cell.setCellValue(masterDatatDto.getDivision());

        cell = dataRow.createCell(cellNumber++);
        cell.setCellValue(masterDatatDto.getProject());

        cell = dataRow.createCell(cellNumber++);
        cell.setCellValue(masterDatatDto.getSiteName());

        if (columnHeader.size() == 4) {
            cell = dataRow.createCell(cellNumber++);
            cell.setCellValue(masterDatatDto.getField1());
            if (masterDatatDto.getField1() == null || masterDatatDto.getField1().trim().equals("")) {
                dataConsistencyList.add(masterDatatDto);
            }
        } else if (columnHeader.size() == 5) {
            cell = dataRow.createCell(cellNumber++);
            cell.setCellValue(masterDatatDto.getField1());

            cell = dataRow.createCell(cellNumber++);
            cell.setCellValue(masterDatatDto.getField2());

            if (masterDatatDto.getField2() == null || masterDatatDto.getField2().trim().equals("")) {
                dataConsistencyList.add(masterDatatDto);
            }

        }
        // Auto sizes column width
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
    }
    createConsistencyCheckFile(dataConsistencyList, columnHeader);
    // Auto sizes column width for data consistency excel
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9 ; i++)
        dataConsistencyWorksheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
        dataConsistencyWorksheet.createFreezePane(0, 1);

}
```

The second class is to check for data consistency(shows that there is no blank data in the database)

```
    private void createConsistencyCheckFile(List<MasterDataDto> dataConsistencyList, List<String> columnHeaders) {
    Cell cell = null;
    Row dataRow = null;
    int cellNumber = 0;
    dataRow = dataConsistencyWorksheet.createRow(dataConsistencyWorksheetRowNumber++);


    cell = dataRow.createCell(cellNumber++);
    cell.setCellValue(dataConsistencyWorksheetRowNumber - 1);


    cell = dataRow.createCell(cellNumber++);
    cell.setCellValue("SUMMARY");

    cell = dataRow.createCell(cellNumber++);
    cell.setCellValue(columnHeaders.size() - 1);

    cell = dataRow.createCell(cellNumber++);
    cell.setCellValue(dataConsistencyList.size());

    for (String columnHeader : columnHeaders) {
        cell = dataRow.createCell(cellNumber++);
        cell.setCellValue(columnHeader);
    }

    for (MasterDataDto masterDatatDto : dataConsistencyList) {

        cellNumber = 0;
        dataRow = dataConsistencyWorksheet.createRow(dataConsistencyWorksheetRowNumber++);

        cell = dataRow.createCell(cellNumber++);
        cell.setCellValue(dataConsistencyWorksheetRowNumber - 1);

        cell = dataRow.createCell(cellNumber++);
        cell.setCellValue("DETAIL");

        cell = dataRow.createCell(cellNumber++);
        cell.setCellValue(columnHeaders.size() - 1);

        cell = dataRow.createCell(cellNumber++);
        cell.setCellValue("N/A");

        cell = dataRow.createCell(cellNumber++);
        cell.setCellValue(masterDatatDto.getDivision());

        cell = dataRow.createCell(cellNumber++);
        cell.setCellValue(masterDatatDto.getProject());

        cell = dataRow.createCell(cellNumber++);
        cell.setCellValue(masterDatatDto.getSiteName());

        if (columnHeaders.size() == 4) {
            cell = dataRow.createCell(cellNumber++);
            cell.setCellValue("???");
        } else if (columnHeaders.size() == 5) {
            cell = dataRow.createCell(cellNumber++);
            cell.setCellValue(masterDatatDto.getField1());

            cell = dataRow.createCell(cellNumber++);
            cell.setCellValue("???");
        }

    }

}
```

Originally I just had the first class and while it take take time to run it did finish. Since I have added the data consistency class portion, it times out after the first sheet that is created.

I have originally used Apache POI because when I used JXL, it does not allow me to insert more than 65,500 records(rows) on one sheet. I have alot to extract. Please let me know if I need to provide more of my program to give a clearer understanding of my issue. I truly appreciate your help in advance

I have another question that I would like to add to this. I am thinking about extracting database data into a CSV file and then take the CSV file and import it to an Excel. One question I have is since I originally was extracting to multiple sheets in a work book, is there a way I can export to multiple CSV files? Then from the multiple CSV files, how can I add them to different sheets in a work book?

Thanks again
Sonny

Hello Doug
Here is my query code:

```
    public List<MasterDataDto> getDFMasterData(int siteValueId, int firstColumnId, int secondColumnId, int divisionId) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    List<MasterDataDto> masterDatatDtoList = new ArrayList<MasterDataDto>();
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
        query.append("Select Distinct Dt.Name Division, Pr.Name Project, Addtl_Type.Name Site_Name, Atprt.Name col1, Atchd.Name col2");
        query.append(" From Addtl_Type_Rel Attr, Addtl_Type_Rel Attchd, Addtl_Type_Rel Attgrch, Addtl_Type  Atprt, Project Pr, Addtl_Type Atchd, Addtl_Type, Division_Type Dt");
        query.append(" Where Pr.Id = Attr.Parent_N_Value");
        query.append(" And Attr.Id = Attchd.Previous_Rel_Id");
        query.append(" And Pr.Division_Type = Dt.Id");
        query.append(" And Atchd.Id = Attgrch.Child_N_Value");
        query.append(" And Attgrch.Parent_Field_Id = Attchd.Child_Field_Id");
        query.append(" And Attchd.Id = Attgrch.Previous_Rel_Id");
        query.append(" And Attr.Child_Field_Id = Attchd.Parent_Field_Id");
        query.append(" And Atprt.Id = Attchd.Child_N_Value");
        query.append(" And Attchd.Parent_N_Value = Addtl_Type.Id");
        query.append(" And Attr.Parent_Field_Id = ?");
        query.append(" And Attr.Child_Field_Id = ?");
        query.append(" And Attchd.Child_Field_Id = ?");
        query.append(" And Attgrch.Child_Field_Id = ?");
        query.append(" And Dt.Id = ?");
        if (siteValueId != 0) {
            query.append(" And Attr.Child_N_Value = ?");
        }
        query.append(" Order By Project, Site_Name, col1, col2");

        con = getConnection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query.toString());
        ps.setInt(1, MasterDataConstants.PROJECT);
        ps.setInt(2, MasterDataConstants.SITE_NAME_ID);
        ps.setInt(3, firstColumnId);
        ps.setInt(4, secondColumnId);
        ps.setInt(5, divisionId);
        if (siteValueId != 0) {
            ps.setInt(6, siteValueId);
        }
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            MasterDataDto masterDataDto = new MasterDataDto();
            masterDataDto.setDivision(rs.getString("Division"));
            masterDataDto.setProject(rs.getString("Project"));
            masterDataDto.setSiteName(rs.getString("Site_Name"));
            masterDataDto.setField1(rs.getString("col1"));
            masterDataDto.setField2(rs.getString("col2"));
            System.out.println(masterDataDto.getDivision() + "\t" + masterDataDto.getProject() + "\t" + masterDataDto.getSiteName() + "\t" + masterDataDto.getField1() + "\t"
                    + masterDataDto.getField2());
            masterDatatDtoList.add(masterDataDto);
        }
    } finally {

        cleanUp(con, ps, rs);
    }
    return masterDatatDtoList;
```

How could I make this more efficient?
Thanks
Sonny

Hello all I have a new issue with this program. I have removed the autoSizeColumn and it reaches the point to where it is about to write to the excel workbooks. I am now getting a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.
Here is the complete stack trace of the error:
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception

root cause

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.resize(Saver.java:1592)
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.preEmit(Saver.java:1223)
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.emit(Saver.java:1144)
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.emitElement(Saver.java:926)
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver.processElement(Saver.java:456)
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver.process(Saver.java:307)
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.saveToString(Saver.java:1727)
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cursor._xmlText(Cursor.java:546)
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cursor.xmlText(Cursor.java:2436)
org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.xmlText(XmlObjectBase.java:1455)
org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.getKey(SharedStringsTable.java:130)
org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.addEntry(SharedStringsTable.java:176)
org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.setCellValue(XSSFCell.java:350)
org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.setCellValue(XSSFCell.java:320)
master.service.MasterDataService.createSiteFieldExcel(MasterDataService.java:1102)
master.service.MasterDataService.createMasterDataFile(MasterDataService.java:886)
master.service.MasterDataServlet.doGet(MasterDataServlet.java:22)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Where do I have to increase the JVM size in eclipse. I am running Tomcat if this helps too.
Thanks
Sonny

Comment: I'm not an expert, but have you tried any profiling tools to determine where most of the execution time is being spent in your program?  Just an idea that could prove useful for you down the road.

Comment: I appreciate your comment. Yes I have added 'println' checkers in my program. It has no problem extracting data to the eclipse console but it takes the most time taking the console values and putting them in an excel. Sonny

Comment: I don't see your query; however, let the database do the heavy lifting.  Change your query to do the the filtering in your WHERE clause. Recently, I was try to do something similar with SSRS; I ran into memory and speed issues. The database is optimized to do the filtering and selection.  Use your jsp to only write the excel file.

Comment: I've notized that using `autoSizeColumn` causes a delay of ~30 seconds on some machines when it is called the first time; I guess it's some kind of timeout. Try what happens when you out-comment `autoSizeColumn` in your program.

Comment: Hello @ammoQ, I removed the autoSizeColumn and it seemed to move much faster. It still times out right before it is about to write to an excel. If I remove the createFreezePane(0, 1) , will this also save some time? Thanks for your input. - Thanks Sonny

Comment: @Doug I have added my query above. because I could not fit it in comments. How could I improve this.

Comment: This is better suited for the sibling **Code Review** forum instead of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Joop Is the Code Review Forum in StackOverflow? Thanks

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ See also the dropdown list above to the left "Stack Overflow" -> Communities

Answer (score 0):

You might use a JDBC driver for Excel, maybe a JDBC ODBC bridge, requiring some Windows fuss.
That would be optimal, as you would need to walk the DB query and could immediately write it to the Excel "database".

http://www.coderanch.com/t/465901/JDBC/databases/insert-data-excel-file-java

Failing that, do no use a list of DTOs but immediately add every rs.next / DTO to the Excel sheet.